# React.js: Passing data between components

Tags: reactjs, parameter-passing

Im learning React and trying not to use class based components, but rather implementing components as functions.

Im have a simple app which performs queries to DB. My components are basically Searchbar  and DataArray , constructed within App .

Im struggling with howto pass the value read in SearchBar (input field query) to a DB query functions, which will then pass the results to DataArray. Props wouldnt work here. Is state the way to go? Then again, how can I read the state from another components, or can I?

What am I missing here?

Any help appreciated here,

br, Mika

Comment: state is indeed the way to go. you need to treat the search bar as controlled component

Comment: You need a state in a parent component and then send this state as props to both child components. You can read more about it here - https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not shared any code, it is a bit difficult to explain but I will try my best.

With the introduction of react hooks, you can handle events in a functional component. Follow this [link](https://jscomplete.com/playground/s470517) to get the sample that I created.

To pass the result to a different component I would like to recommend react's build-in function called context. Here is a [link](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively) of an article on the same.

This is not a full solution but it will guide you in the right direction.

Happy learning.

Comment: Thanks for the example, Im getting the form control now. I took a look at contexts but it just seems quite overwhelming.
I tried to add state to my App component as pass it down to the SearchBar as props. Then I tried to set the input value from SearchBar back to App components. Would this be working solution?

Im getting error saying : TypeError: Cannot create property 'setQuery' on string ''

Here is a link to the modified code:
https://jscomplete.com/playground/s477960

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with React Hooks. GET_REQUEST depends on what kind of HTTP-request you want to do.

```js
const SearchBar = () => {
  const [myStateVariable, setMyStateVariable] = useState(null)
  
  const { loading, data } = useQuery(GET_REQUEST, {
    variables: "my_request_param"
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!loading && data) {
      setMyStateVariable(data)
    }
  }, data)

  return (
    !loading && (
      <DataArray propsVariable={myStateVariable} />
    )
  )
}

const DataArray = ({ propsVariable }) => {
  return (
    <div>My variable from request: {propsVariable}<div/>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is useQuery a React native method? I was thinking of using Fetch API or Axios. So does useEffect() act as an async code block?